# Instantiate child class with the parent's constructor in Python multiprocessing

Tags: multiprocessing, fork, python-multiprocessing, spawn

The class `MyProcess()` inherits from `multiprocessing.Process()`. How can I spawn `MyProcess()` with different [contexts](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods). E.g., fork, spawn, or forkserver.

```py
class MyProcess(multiprocessing.Process):
    """It inherits from multiprocessing.Process and overloads run()."""
    def __init__(
        self,
        fn: Callable,
        **kwargs,
    ):
        super().__init__()
        self.fn = fn
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def run(self):
        self.fn(**self.kwargs)
```

In the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods), it shows the process can be generated by `ctx`

```py
def foo(q):
    q.put('hello')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ctx = mp.get_context('spawn')
    q = ctx.Queue()
    p = ctx.Process(target=foo, args=(q,))
    p.start()
    print(q.get())
    p.join()
```

I know I can use `mp.set_start_method('spawn')` at the beginning of the code, but I want to create two processes, one with spawn, one with fork like below.

```py
def funcA(a):
    print(f"hello {a}")

def funcB(b):
    print(f"world {b}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    mp.set_start_method('fork')
    ctx = mp.get_context('spawn')

    p1 = mp.Process(target=funcA, args=("Lucy")) # fork
    p2 = ctx.Process(target=funcB, args=("Sarah") # spawn

    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```

My question is that `multiprocessing` does not have `MyProcess()` class. How can I use `ctx.MyProcess()` to create it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can inherit from the specific versions of the `Process` class from `multiprocessing.context`:

```py
class MySpawningProcess(multiprocessing.context.SpawnProcess):
    pass

class MyForkingProcess(multiprocessing.context.ForkProcess):
    pass
```

Be careful with digging too deep into the private namespace however.. There's a good amount of state to keep track of. In particular, I did not look into how `ForkServerProcess` would respond to subclassing (all contexts are module globals).